# Relation between Lie group characters and spherical functions on symmetric spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

**Setup:** Let $G/K$ be an irreducible compact Riemannian symmetric space, where $G$ is a simply connected compact real Lie group, and $K$ is the maximal compact connected subgroup of some noncompact real form of $G$.

If $\chi$ is the character of some finite-dimensional irreducible representation $V$ of $G$, which is spherical (meaning that the set $V^K$ of $K$-fixed vectors in $V$ is nonzero), I understand that $V^K$ is one-dimensional, and we can define the unique (up to a constant) zonal spherical function $\varphi$ associated to $\chi$ by: $\varphi(g) := \int_{k\in K} \chi(gk)$ [Helgason 1984, theorem IV.4.2].  This is left and right $K$-invariant, in other words, it can be seen as a function on the double coset space $K\backslash G/K$.

Now $K\backslash G/K$ has a nice description: if $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} + \mathfrak{p}$ is the Cartan decomposition of the Lie algebra of $G$ into that of $K$ and complement, and $\mathfrak{a}$ a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak{p}$, then $H\mapsto\mathbf{e}(H) := \exp(2\pi H)$ defines a bijection from a Weyl alcove in $\mathfrak{a}$ to $K\backslash G/K$ [Helgason 1978, theorem VII.8.6].  This suggests that we look at $\varphi\circ\mathbf{e}$ on $\mathfrak{a}$, which is invariant under the Weyl group of the restricted root system.

My questions are about $\varphi\circ\mathbf{e}$, its relation with $\chi\circ\mathbf{e}$ on $\mathfrak{a}$, and their Fourier transforms: essentially, I think I understand the case of a compact Lie group and I am trying to get a grasp on the analogous situation for a symmetric space:

**Questions:**

- What can we say about the relation between the functions $\varphi\circ\mathbf{e}$ and $\chi\circ\mathbf{e}$ on $\mathfrak{a}$ (I used to think that they coincide, but evidently it's much more complicated)?
- More precisely, if we introduce the Fourier transform, a.k.a., the weight decomposition, of $\varphi\circ\mathbf{e}$ (i.e., writing $\varphi(\mathbf{e}(H)) = \sum_\Lambda \widehat\varphi(\Lambda)\,\mathbf{e}(\langle\Lambda,H\rangle)$ for $H\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $\Lambda$ ranging over the lattice dual to $\{H\in\mathfrak{a} : \mathbf{e}(H)\in K\}$, I am talking about the values $\widehat\varphi(\Lambda)$).  The question of understanding $\widehat\chi$ is well answered by highest weight theory and the various formulæ of Weyl, Kostant and Freudenthal ($\widehat\chi(\Lambda)$ is the multiplicity of the weight $\Lambda$ in $V$).  What analogous theory or formulæ exist for $\widehat\varphi$, if any?
- Specifically, does the support of $\widehat\varphi$ equal that of $\widehat\chi$ restricted to (the dual space to) $\mathfrak{a}$?  Are the values of $\widehat\varphi$ even integers (up to a common constant)?  Do they relate to the multiplicities $\widehat\chi(\Lambda)$ of $\chi$?  And most importantly: how can $\widehat\varphi$ be computed algorithmically?

These questions were asked in a fairly naïve way, I am starting to realize that they are not so naïve, but even though I have found a few references, I still struggle to form a picture of what is known about $\widehat\varphi$, and whether it can reasonably be computed algorithmically.

References:

- Helgason 1978: *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups and Symmetric Spaces*
- Helgason 1984: *Groups and Geometric Analysis (Integral Geometry, Invariant Differential Operators, and Spherical Functions)*

Additional references found after asking the question:

- Takeuchi 1994: *Modern Spherical Functions* (monograph translated from the 1975 Japanese original) [pointed out by Francois Ziegler in the comments]
- Vretare 1976: "Elementary Spherical Functions on Symmetric Spaces" (*Math. Scand.* **39** 343–358) [seems to answer a few questions, such as that of the set of appearing weights]
- Clerc 1988: "Fonctions Sphériques des Espaces Symétriques Compacts" (*Trans. Amer. Math. Soc* **306** 421–431)

I imagine that since none of these references give any sort of analogue of Weyl's character formula, this means that none is known (or perhaps even that none is *possible* for some reason?).  I would still like to know more.

Comment: I believe Takeuchi ([1994](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1280269), Thm 8.3) expresses $\varphi\circ\mathbf e$ as a linear combination of characters which involves more than just $\chi\circ\mathbf e$ unless we are in the group case (Remark (2) following).

Comment: Does the work on "Non abelian Fourier analysis" not cover this?

Comment: @Suvrit Non abelian harmonic (Fourier) analysis is indeed the general framework (I should have mentioned the Peter-Weyl theorem along the way), but my question is more specific: in the case of $G/K$ a symmetric space, much more can be said than for any quotient $G/H$, e.g., the convolution algebra of $K$-bi-invariant functions is commutative and has this orthogonal basis of "zonal spherical functions" which looks very much like the case of class functions (aka central functions, conjugation-invariant) functions on $G$ itself. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) For class functions on $G$ we have this very nice expression of characters given by Weyl's character formula and the formulæ of Kostant and Freudenthal, which gives a very good grip on the conjugation invariant part of $L^2(G)$.  I am trying to understand the analogous situation for $K$-bi-invariant functions on $G$ (the "zonal" part of $L^2(G/K)$).  So while non abelian harmonic analysis describes all of $L^2(G)$, it is much less precise (and less computational!) than what I am hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context -- the only other comment I have is whether there's anything of use for you in the book *Analysis on symmetric cones*

Comment: Just as a comment, for the simplest example $SO(3)/SO(2)$, the spherical functions are Legendre polynomials, and it seems that there is no simple relation to the characters.